# Can a WPF Expander expand down/left instead of down/right?

Tags: wpf, expander

When an expander expands down, the content and the header are left-aligned, so it is really expanding down/right. Is it possible to make it expand down/right, so the header and the content are right-aligned?

I don't want to shift the header when it expands. The header should stay where it is.

Thanks

Comment: Whaaaat? "it is really expanding Down/right... is it possible to expand down/right" - Whaaat? What do you mean? Expander expands increasing its desired height (means y axis). Which axis are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `HorizontalAlignment` and the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Right for down+left expansion.

To align the header and arrow on the right, you will need to author a new control template for it, or copy the existing one [in blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908.aspx).